# Allowing users to highlight text in app for iOS (AS3)

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I am creating an app which generates conjugations for Japanese verbs.
I would much like the generated text to have the ability that people can highlight the text to copy it to clipboard on an iOS device if they need to.
So far I am able to make it work with android OS, windows, OSX and browser.
For some reason though I am unable to get it to work in iOS.
The only option I have enabled is the "Highlightable" option in flash and with this small option enabled it works in every single platform but iOS.

Has anyone else run into this issue? Is it a limitation of iOS?